# expose autogenerated OPTIONS endpoint hapi-swagger

Tags: node.js, swagger, hapi.js, hapi-swagger

We're leveraging the hapi-swagger plugin to generate swagger documentation for endpoints we are proxying in Azure's API gateway service. We're exporting the swagger doc, and importing it into the Azure service.

All of our endpoints are set to `cors: true`, and because we are making cross origin requests, common browsers (e.g. Chrome) make a preflight OPTIONS request. Apparently Hapi automatically generates the OPTIONS endpoints for us (as in, we see the OPTIONS requests being made successfully in the browser), but it also seems that our exported swagger doc does not include these OPTIONS endpoints, and so none of the endpoints get proxied in the gateway service.

Is anyone aware of a way to export/expose these OPTIONS endpoints?

Additional information:

- hapi: 16.6.2
- hapi-swagger: 8.0.0

Answer (score 0):

We "solved" this by turning on CORS support for each of our proxied endpoints in the Azure gateway which I guess automatically exposes OPTIONS endpoints (I wasn't doing the Azure work, so forgive my untechnical explanation; this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-cors-support) seems to corroborate my understanding, though it's about Azure storage services, not their api service..).